Why can't I request by pricebook name?
I'm trying to query pricebook by name and it return 0 results in flow, raw query or in code.
Is there any other way to find a pricebook by name ?

Pricebook Not found


Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  This query works for me.  Did you copy and paste the Standard Price Book name from something else?  It is possible there is a  hidden Unicode character in the name.  Have you tried other query tools like Developer Console > Query Editor?

This works in other sandboxes, but not in this one!
I have tried several other pricebook names, but none of them are functioning.
As mentioned, it doesn't even work with the "contains" function in flows.
Is this issue specific to this sandbox?

for the sandbox in question - is the sharing model for Pricebook set to No access ?
